# Material table page size change performance issue in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am using the material table with Angular 7. On one screen there are around 7000 records. The table loads fine with page size 10 or 20 or 100. But when I change the page size to All (7000) in this case, then it does not display and chrome crashes with error "Page Unresponsive".

Please note that table data is already loaded for the first time so it is not related to API.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected for Chrome to go unresponsive as that operation could be very memory heavy.

3 things I can recommend you can try:

1. Get rid of **All** from pagination (no one is going to scroll 7000 records, instead implement filtering)
2. Try server-side pagination to get around you current problem
3. Look for [virtual scroll](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10122) for mat-table